# Как подменить IP адрес отправителя на C#?

Tags: c#, сеть, tcp

Вопрос заключается в следующем: 
можно ли отправить простой TCP сокет с левым IP адресом? Возможно ли такое реализовать  на C#? И если возможно, то каким образом?
Слышал, что это называется IP Spoofing, и Raw sockets, но конкретных реализаций именно отправки не нашел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно реализовать с использованием "стороннего компьютера", но предварительно на него вам нужно будет набросить (службу,программу с tcplistner) на ней сделать ретранслятор вашего запроса и фактически ваш ip останется на "стороннем компьютере", а пакет отправится уже с ip "стороннего компьютера".

Comment: ответ-то хороший, но явно не на тот вопрос, который написан в верхней части страницы.

Comment: А что именно вы хотели, чтобы предложили пути размещения таких служб(программ) на сторонних компьютерах? Так это отдельный вопрос. Есть много способов.

Comment: вопрос касается поля «[ip-адрес источника](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)» (и хотя по ошибке упомянут протокол tcp, а не ip, я думаю, это простительно). а у вас ход мысли идёт совсем в другую плоскость. впрочем, автор вопроса, возможно, отказался от своей идеи («[ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)», может быть, а вы как раз и предложили то, что ему на самом деле требовалось).